# JMSException deserializing XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, exception, jms, activemq-classic

I have a JMS ObjectMessage. In this ObjectMessage is an Object with XMLGregorianCalendar. I can put the object in the JMS queue, but when I take it I get the following JMSException.

```
15:01:49,967 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) javax.jms.JMSException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.SerializedXMLGregorianCalendar from [Module "org.apache.activemq.artemis" version 2.6.3.jbossorg-00014 from local module loader @3da30852 (finder: local module finder @403f0a22 (roots: C:\Temp\dev_openjdk\wildfly16\modules,C:\Temp\dev_openjdk\wildfly16\modules\system\layers\base))]

15:01:49,968 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)

15:01:49,968 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)

15:01:49,969 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)

15:01:49,969 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)

15:01:49,969 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

15:01:49,970 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)

15:01:49,970 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:693)

15:01:49,970 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass0(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:157)

15:01:49,971 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:108)

15:01:49,972 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1886)

15:01:49,973 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)

15:01:49,973 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)

15:01:49,973 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)

15:01:49,974 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)

15:01:49,975 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)

15:01:49,976 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)

15:01:49,977 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)

15:01:49,977 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)

15:01:49,978 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)

15:01:49,978 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)

15:01:49,978 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)

15:01:49,978 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)

15:01:49,980 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)

15:01:49,980 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)

15:01:49,980 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)

15:01:49,980 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)

15:01:49,986 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:153)

15:01:49,986 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at deployment.MeMi_Service.war//com.test.queue.QueueMessageListener.onMessage(QueueMessageListener.java:26)

15:01:49,986 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:107)

15:01:49,987 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1011)

15:01:49,987 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50)

15:01:49,988 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1134)

15:01:49,988 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)

15:01:49,988 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)

15:01:49,988 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66)

15:01:49,989 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

15:01:49,989 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

15:01:49,989 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads))     at org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
```

What is the reason for this exception? I do not know what this exception would indicate.

Is there a problem here with the deserialization of the XMLGregorianCalendar or can not a necessary package be loaded?

Comment: Looks like a serialization issue, not exactly a JMS or ActiveMQ issue. The source code at https://github.com/MaTriXy/xerces-for-android/blob/master/src/mf/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/SerializedXMLGregorianCalendar.java suggests DatatypeFactoryImpl not being found.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis of my problem. But what can I do about it?

Comment: Well, try to change what you can change. Is xerces controlling which class you use ? If so, talk to the xerces people or try a dfferent version.

Comment: I myself do not use these libraries directly. These libraries are included in the Wildfly 16. So I do not know how to influence it. But I can not be the only one who uses XMLGregorianCalendar via JMS on the Wildfly. Therefore, I assume that it is a configuration problem. I just do not know one thing.

Comment: I could not solve the problem. I have now changed all data types from type XML to Calendar. Now it works first. But if someone still has a solution, I would be pleased about this.